# my program just crash after for loop ?any solution for that?

Tags: c

i am trying to make a program that create a list of custommers and then editing the list like i want by deleting , adding a customer before another etc , for some reason i didnt find out yet why my program crash after displaying custommers exact after using function afficher();

test:main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "liste.h"
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    liste data;
    printf("creation liste . . .\n");   /*list creation*/
    creer_liste(&data);
    if (data.premier == NULL)
    {
        printf("done!\n");
    }

    int nb, i;
    printf("combien de personnes souhaitez ajouter a la liste?\n");
    scanf("%d", &nb);   /*reading number of custommers*/
    personne p1;
    for (i=0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        printf("donner le nom de la personne %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%20s", p1.nom);
        printf("donner l'annee de naissance de la personne %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &p1.annee_naissance);
        printf("donner le numero de telephone de la personne %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%20s", p1.tel);
        ajouter_en_tete(p1, &data); /*add custommer info in the begenning of list*/
    }
    afficher(data); /*displaying list*/

    int pos;
    printf("veuillez ajouter un element avant un autre?\n");
    printf("donner la position de cette element:\n");
    scanf("%d", &pos);  /*reading position of the custommer that you want to insert before it*/

    cellule *add_elt;
    add_elt = data.premier;
    for (i = 1; i < pos; i++)
    {
        add_elt = add_elt->suivant;
    }

    printf("donner le nom de la nouvelle personne:\n");
    scanf("%s", p1.nom);

    printf("donner l'annee de naissance de la nouvelle personne %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &p1.annee_naissance);

    printf("donner le numero de telephone de la nouvelle personne %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%s", p1.tel);

    ajouter_avant(add_elt, p1, &data);  /*adding the new customer info*/

    afficher(data);
}/*displaying*/
```

Prototypes:

```
#ifndef LISTE_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTE_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct
{
    char nom[20];
    int annee_naissance;
    char tel[20];
} personne; /*every customer has a name , date of birth and phone */

typedef struct noeud
{
    personne p;
    struct noeud *suivant;
} cellule;  /*node contains the custommer info and the next address*/

typedef struct
{
    cellule *premier;
} liste;    /*list that has one entry*/

void creer_liste(liste *);  /*creation*/
void ajouter_en_tete(personne, liste *);    /*adding at begenening of list*/
void ajouter_en_queue(personne, liste *);   /*adding to the end of list*/
void supprimer_element(cellule *, liste *); /*deleting element*/
void afficher(liste);   /*displaying list*/
void ajouter_apres(cellule *, personne, liste *);   /*adding after a custommer*/
void ajouter_avant(cellule *, personne, liste *);   /*adding before a custommer*/

#endif // LISTE_H_INCLUDED
```

Implementation:

```
#include "liste.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void creer_liste(liste *ll)
{
    assert(ll);
    ll->premier=NULL;
}

void ajouter_en_tete(personne pp, liste *ll)
{
    assert(ll);
    cellule *nouveau;
    nouveau = (cellule *) malloc(sizeof(cellule));  /*allocating the new node to add*/
    nouveau->p = pp;    /*getting the new info*/
    if (ll->premier == NULL)
        ll->premier = nouveau;  /*case list is empty only list start's pointer updated*/
    else
    {
        nouveau->suivant = ll->premier; /*the next pointer of the new custommer take the old list start's pointer */
        ll->premier = nouveau;  /*list's start pointer get updated by th new node*/
    }
}

void ajouter_en_queue(personne pp, liste *ll)
{
    assert(ll);

    cellule *nouveau;
    nouveau = (cellule *) malloc(sizeof(cellule));
    nouveau->p = pp;
    if (ll->premier == NULL)
        ll->premier = nouveau;
    else
    {
        while (ll->premier->suivant != NULL)
            ll->premier = ll->premier->suivant;
        ll->premier = nouveau;
    }
}

void supprimer_element(cellule *sup_elt, liste *ll)
{
    assert(sup_elt && ll);

    if (ll->premier)
    {
        cellule *temp;
        if (sup_elt)
        {
            if (sup_elt->suivant == NULL)
            {
                free(sup_elt);
            }
            else
            {
                temp = sup_elt->suivant;
                *sup_elt = *temp;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

void ajouter_avant(cellule *q, personne pp, liste *ll)
{
    assert(ll);

    cellule *temp;
    temp = (cellule *) malloc(sizeof(cellule));
    temp = q->suivant;
    *temp = *q;
    q->p = pp;
}

void afficher(liste ll)
{
    assert(ll.premier);
    if (ll.premier != NULL)
    {
        cellule *actuel;
        actuel = ll.premier;
        while (actuel != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\t%d\t%s\n", actuel->p.nom, actuel->p.annee_naissance, actuel->p.tel);
            actuel = actuel->suivant;
        }/*parcouring the list and displaying every custommer till reaching adress NULL*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use whitespace to make your code legible

Comment: Please use indentation to make your code legible.

Comment: okay i will edit

Comment: Is your keyboard playing up. The spacebar does not seem to be working

Comment: BTW - In this unreadable code I did notice you are casting `malloc`. The is bad. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Ed Heal Sorry, I just dropped my code without significant comments now I edited it should be more readable and about the casting I learned at uni making it this way idk if not casting it make any difference.

Comment: Please follow the link

Comment: Please check the return values from `scanf`. Also `scanf("%s", p1.tel);` -> `scanf("%19s", p1.tel);` to prevent buffer overruns

Comment: I checked `scanf` return values should be good I am guessing the problem is in the `afficher() ` because when deleting this function from code, program doesn't crash

Comment: Nothing in the code to check return values from `scanf`

Comment: `scanf("%20s", p1.nom);`  Should be ` scanf("%19s", p1.nom);` - Null character

Comment: Yeah I edited to `%19s` in my own code and I checked by accessing the address of`p1. nom`and displaying it

Comment: Check the others and check the return values i.e `if (scanf(..) != 1) ....`

Comment: Your best bet is to read the manual page for `scanf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ajouter_en_tete*()`, when you allocate `nouveau`, `malloc()` does not initialise any field, so `suivante` might not be `NULL` unless you explicitly set it.

More specifically, you check `if (ll->premier == NULL)`, and:

- set `ll->premier = nouveau` in both cases (move that out of the `if` block).
- Only update `nouveau->suivante` in the second case, so it's never set to `NULL`. Might as well move that out of the `if` block too, so it will always be set (and in the case of `NULL`, it's set to `NULL` as it should be.

I'll show what I mean.

```
1 nouveau = (cellule *) malloc(sizeof(cellule));
2 nouveau->p = pp;
3 nouveau->suivant = ll->premier;
4 ll->premier = nouveau;
```

After line 1 and 2, `nouveau->suivant` is probably not NULL. If the list is empty, `ll->premier` is `NULL`, so in line 3 `nouveau->suivant` also gets set to `NULL`. In line 4 `ll->premier` is set to `nouveau`.

Next time through, same as before `nouveau->suivant` is not NULL at line 2, at line 3 `nouveau->suivant` is set to `ll->premier` which was the node allocated last time, and `ll->premier` is set to `nouveau`. The node from last time is unchanged, at this point `ll->premier->suivant` is the previous node, `ll->premier->suivant->suivant` is still NULL.

In all cases, it works this way.

Comment: I didn't understand you well can you demonstrate it with a portion of code, also in case `ll->premier=NULL`it means list is empty and in this case only the pointer `ll->premier` will be updated why you want me to move it out of `if` loop, in the second case when list not empty both pointers have to be updated the `nouveau->suivant` take the adress of the old `ll->premier` and then `ll->premier`get updated with the new adress to make sure the new node is on the head of list. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `nouveau->suivant` Should be set either way in the procedure

Comment: How? by moving it out `if` loop?

Comment: Thank you so muchh, now I got what you mean `nouveau->suivant` will set to `NULL` when the list is empty so no need for `if` loop thank you so much now my program works like charm :)